# Stuck in fastboot oem unlock (Fly IQ4503)

Tags: adb, fastboot

Trying to install another OS on my Android phone.
Fly it isn't so popular phone, so I have lots of problems within installation. Also I used for this my laptop with Ubuntu 15.10. Now I'm trying to unlock oem with this command:

```
sudo fastboot oem unlock
```

and in my terminal just showed this: ... That's all.
After tipping this:

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

my phone doesn't have normal bootloader with Android and title "Start", it has just grey screen and with inscription "fastboot mode 2 (NORMAL)" with green color.
So, what I should to do in this situation? How can I to unlock oem on my phone?
Thank's a lot.

Comment: after `adb reboot boot loader` oem unlock doesn't work - it says "FAILED(remote: :unknown oem command)". Then I type `sudo fastboot continue` - it works, and screen changes to black. Just black screen. Fastboot can find device ??????, but oem command working, that I said. I understand, that ... - it's mean waiting my answer on phone, I should confirm. But I don't have any messages in my phone, just black screen. Can I confirm it from console in laptop?

Comment: I have the same problem on a Lenovo A7600-H.

`fasbtoot oem unlock`, and in fact `fastboot oem <anything>`
the terminal shows `...` and doesn't return.